# Best way to save an email attached to an email as an *.eml file in c# using Microsoft Graph library

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following situation: an Email with another email as attachment. I'm working in C# using Microsoft.Graph library on an Microsoft 365 account.

As far as I know, I can stream and save the parent email with the following code:

```
Message m; // m is the parent email that I want to save retrieved with an GetAsync() call
var stream = await graphClient.Me.Messages[m.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();
var filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\attachments\" + "emailID" + ".eml";
using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
            }
```

But I cannot do the same with the attached email: I cannot get the `Content` for the inner email. At the moment I can access to the inner email and read the body, in this way:

```
var attachmentRequest = graphClient.Me.Messages[m.Id].Attachments[attachment.Id].Request().Expand("microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item").GetAsync();
var itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment)attachmentRequest.Result;
var itemMessage = (Message)itemAttachment.Item;
```

But saving only the `Body` is not the intended behaviour. I would like to save the object as an .eml file, in order to open it with Microsoft Outlook client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is outside of the scope of the Graph API and C# SDK itself.

I would suggest to use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) nuget. `MimeKit` has a class called [MimeMessage](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm).

You can create a new `MimeMessage` and map/set each field from the `Microsoft.Graph.Message` object.

```
var itemMessage = (Message)itemAttachment.Item;
```

`MimeMessage` has method [WriteTo](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_MimeMessage_WriteTo.htm) which allows you to write the message to the specified output stream. You can save the message directly to a file.

Comment: many thanks, the library is very useful. best